# Sum of values between start and end date in MATLAB

Tags: algorithm, matlab

If, in MATLAB, I have a set of start **and** end dates that represent a contiguous period of time, how would I take a separate daily time series and accumulate any values from said time series over each start/end pair?

Is this something that can be done with `accumarray()`?  It wasn't clear to me whether it would be efficient to construct the vector that groups each element of the time series by start/end pair.

```
Inputs

Start Date    End Date

01/01/12      01/31/12
02/01/12      02/28/12
...

Date          Value

01/01/12      23
01/02/12      87
01/03/12      5
01/04/12      12
...
02/01/12      4

Output

Start Date    End Date    Value

01/01/12      01/31/12    127
02/01/12      02/28/12    4
...
```

Comment: So you have 3 variables, a vector of measurements, a vector of timestamps for each measurment, and a set of start and end dates between which you want to compute the sum of the measurement?

Comment: @PatternMatching can you please provide a sample input and output?

Comment: @slayton, exactly correct, couldn't have said it better myself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For consecutive periods of time, the following approach might work. Note that the strings containing dates are cellstrings and, for consecutive data, only the first column of your start date /end date matrix is necesssary.

Furthermore, note that I separated your time series data into two variables for the sake of clarity.

```
dateBins = {...
    '01/01/12';
    '02/01/12';
    '03/01/12';
    '04/01/12'};

dates = {
    '01/01/12'
    '01/02/12'
    '01/03/12'
    '01/04/12'
    '02/01/12'    };

values = [
    23
    87
    5
    12
    4];
```

With these variables, the following code

```
[thrash, idx] = histc(datenum(dates), datenum(dateBins))

accumVal = accumarray(idx, values);

result = zeros(length(dateBins), 1); 
result(1:length(accumVal),1) = accumVal;
```

will result in:

```
result =

   127
     4
     0
     0
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have already got two vectors with the start dates and end dates in a format that you can use to compare and you just want to count how many occurrences there are in each cateogory, then it is quite straightforward:

```
% Your data
Dates = 25*rand(10,1);
StartDate = [1 10 20];
EndDate = [9 19 29];

% The Calculation
Result = zeros(size(StartDate)); %Initialization
for d = 1:length(startdate)
    idx = dates >= StartDate & dates <= EndDate;
    Result(d) = sum(idx);
end
```

Note that this will require that you store your dates in a comparable format.

Answer (score 1):

I would iterate over each pair of start/end dates. Then pick out the index start/stop pairs and sum them. If you use `datestr`s, you can make the following less brittle, while allowing for more flexibility in how you represent times that cross years, etc.

```
start_date = {'01/01/12'};
end_date={'01/31/12'};
datevec={'01/01/12','01/02/12','01/03/12','01/31/12'};
values=[23,87,5,12];

for i=1:numel(start_date)

    is = find(ismember(datevec,start_date{i})==1);
    ie = find(ismember(datevec,end_date{i})==1);

    sum(values(is:ie))

end
```